# Scroll background in fixed element?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get the `background` of my `fixed` element to move (change `background-position`)
 
while scrolling the page down.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgbuknwj/1/)

I've made a small animation to demonstrate the effect I want.

---

### CODE:

```
#nav-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
box-shadow: 5px 2px 3px gray;
background: url('triangular.png');
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 200%;
width: 142px;
z-index: 8;
/*animation: movebg 1s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: movebg 1s infinite linear;*/
}

@keyframes movebg {
0% {background-position: 0 0;}

100% {background-position: 60px 60px;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes movebg {
0% {background-position: 0 0;}

100% {background-position: 60px 60px;}

}
```

---

```
<body class="pure-u-1">

    <div id="bg-container">
    </div>

    <div id="nav-container">

        <span id="logo-nav">

        </span>

        <nav id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#etusivu">Etusivu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tietoa">Tietoa Meistä</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#hinnasto">Hinnasto</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Yhteystiedot</a>
            </li>
        </nav>

</div>

<div id="wrapper" class="pure-u-1">

<div id="sivu-1" class="pure-u-1">

<div id="logo">

&nbsp;

</div>

<img src="kuntosali.jpg" class="pure-img"></img>

<!--
<video autoplay id="bgvid" src="kuntosali.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
-->

</div>

<div id="sivu-2">
<span>
    - "Keski-Uudenmaan uusin ja nykyaikaisin kuntosali" -
    </span>
</div>
```

A CSS3 solution, if possible, is appreciated.
If not, jQuery is a secondary option.

Comment: This isn't possible. Your element's position is `fixed` which means that scrolls with the page. You could only get around this by making it transparent and having that background on a static element positioned directly below it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly beat me to it. Set your background on an element below - or even the entire page - then fix a transparent navbar.

Comment: @Claudio I dont get the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need: I've put an absolutely positioned background that heights the entire page and then put fixed item over.

[JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/ur44fox1/1)

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

#bg-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 3px gray;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/gsXrvJ8.png');
    width: 142px;
    z-index: 2; 
}

#nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 142px;
    height: 200%;
    z-index: 8; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good idea! But my page is way longer than 100%, and I can't really measure the height of it, so the background stops after 100%. How could I fix this? Fixed position would've solved this.

Comment: If i'm not wrong... just put `position: relative` to the body and absolute positioned backgrounded object will fullfill 100%... in the fiddle it works.

Comment: `position: relative` pretty much breaks the page. At least the `bg-container` goes somewhere away from the screen...

Comment: could you please post some HTML?  i'll check it out.

Comment: Could you put in fiddler with a position relative and we could see the problem? Thank you!